# MatLab: how to define (not constant) properties that depend on other properties?

Tags: matlab, class, oop, properties

In the following class

```
classdef ClassCar
  properties (Constant)
    % Car phyisical properties
    m = 1630;         % [kg]
    R_rim = 14*.0254; % [m]
    e_tire = .175*.55; % [m]
    R_e = ClassCar.R_rim + ClassCar.e_tire;                   % <= HERE

    % Car transmission properties
    gearRatios = [3.154 1.925 1.281 .951 .756];
    finalDrive = 3.05; %Rapport de differentiel
    overallRatios = ClassCar.gearRatios * ClassCar.finalDrive;% <= HERE
  end
end
```

I want to have composed properties which depend on other properties (as a shortcut). I.e. to retrieve from an instanciated object (car = ClassCar)

```
car.R_e
```

or

```
car.overallRatios
```

**The problem is R_e is a function of R_rim and e_tire.**
**With (Constant) properties, it works**, but the problem is I want those properties **not constant**, and simply removing the keyword causes problems.

Then I tried to do it with help of methods

```
classdef ClassCar
  properties
    % Car phyisical properties
    m = 1630;         % [kg]
    R_rim = 14*.0254; % [m]
    e_tire = .175*.55; % [m]

    % Car transmission properties
    gearRatios = [3.154 1.925 1.281 .951 .756];
    finalDrive = 3.05; %Rapport de differentiel
  end
  methods (Static)
    function value = R_e()
        value = R_rim + e_tire;                       % <= HERE
    end
    function value = overallRatios()
        value = gearRatios * finalDrive;
    end
  end
end
```

But even with keyword (Static) for method, I get **error message** "Undefined function or variable 'R_rim'." I tried typing self.R_rim, ClassCar.R_rim, in vain.

**How to achieve that? Is this the best way to do ?** If so, how to access the object's properties (sthg like self.value)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for are [dependent properties](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/access-methods-for-dependent-properties.html). These are listed as properties, but have their own methods for getting (or setting) values:

```
classdef ClassCar
   properties
      R_Rim = 14*.0254;
      e_tire = .175*.55;
   end
   properties (Dependent)
      R_e
   end
   methods
      function val = get.R_e(obj)
          val = obj.R_rim + obj.e_tire;
      end
   end

end
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Comment: And, better than just that, the properties R_rim and e_tire don't have to be (Constant) actually, and that's the best part of it! (I've edited your answer)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the answer: one need to code proper dedicated functions.
I didn't know the syntax of methods...

See working code:

```
classdef ClassCar
  properties
    % Car phyisical properties
    m = 1630;         % [kg]
    R_rim = 14*.0254; % [m]
    e_tire = .175*.55; % [m]
    % Car transmission properties
    gearRatios = [3.154 1.925 1.281 .951 .756];
    finalDrive = 3.05; %Rapport de differentiel
  end
  methods
    function val = R_e(obj)
        val  = obj.R_rim + obj.e_tire;
    end
    function val = overallRatios(obj)
        val = obj.gearRatios * obj.finalDrive;
    end
  end
end
```